# Dart Convert String to Number

Tags: string, flutter, dart, integer

Here is the Python Equivalent

```
>>> print(int.from_bytes(b'hello world', byteorder='big'))
126207244316550804821666916
```

I need to do the same thing in Dart and get the number as BigInt.

Comment: dart also has `BigInt` dataType

Comment: You can try https://pub.dev/packages/crypto, this may give you some hint

Answer (score 0):

Ok... so here is one way of converting this stuff...

```
BigInt bytes2num(List<int> bytes) {
  BigInt result = BigInt.zero;
  final v = BigInt.from(256);
  for (final val in bytes) {
    result = result * v + BigInt.from(val);
  }
  return result;
}

List<int> num2bytes(BigInt b) {
  final length = (b.bitLength + 7) ~/ 8;
  List<int> result = [];
  final v = BigInt.from(255);
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result.add((b >> (i * 8) & v).toInt());
  }
  return result.reversed.toList();
}

final num = bytes2num('hello world'.codeUnits);
// num: 126207244316550804821666916

final text = String.fromCharCodes(num2bytes(num));
// text: 'hello world'
```